# Find the minimum $K$ such that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} \leq K\sqrt{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The question is to find the minimum $K$ such that $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} \leq K\sqrt{a+b+c}$$ holds true for all non-negative $a,b$ and $c$.

**My attempt:**

I used Cauchy-Schwarz to get
$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{{a+b}}}\right)^2\leq(a+b+c)\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\right)$$

I now have to find the maximum value of $\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\right)$. Putting $\frac ba=x, \frac cb=y$ and $\frac ac=z$, this reduces to the problem of finding the maximum value of $$\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1+z}$$ under the constraint $xyz=1$.

I didn't get any further than this, and I'm pretty sure that my approach is wrong. For the last expression, we find that the case where $x=y=z=1$ is *not* the maximum as the expression is greater than $\frac32$ for $x=\frac12,y=\frac12,z=4$ (It is equal to $\frac{23}{15}$).

I found [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049650/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fraca-sqrtab-leq-frac-sqrt334-sqrta) which doesn't have an answer yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

(I found this question [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/inspired-by-daniel-liu-4/))

In [this similar question](https://brilliant.org/problems/a-very-hard-inequality/), the maximum doesn't appear to be attained in the case where $x=y=z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a=3$, $b=1$ and $c=0$ we obtain $k\geq\frac{5}{4}.$

We'll prove that $\frac{5}{4}$ is a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}\leq\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{a+b+c}.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\sqrt{\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}\right)^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+4b+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(2a+4b+c)}{a+b}}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+4b+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(2a+4b+c)}{a+b}\leq\frac{25(a+b+c)}{16}$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}ab(4a+b)(a+2b)^2(a-3b)^2+$$
$$+abc\sum_{cyc}(122a^4+217a^3b+143a^3c+564a^2b^2+1338a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts

Let $x=b/a, y=c/b, z=a/c$. This transforms the inequality to

$$2≥f(x,y,z)≥1,f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1+z}$$
Under the constraint $xyz=1$ (as you have shown).

Now
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=\frac{(1+y)(1+z)+(1+z)(1+x)+(1+x)}{(1+y)(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}\\
&=\frac{3+2(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)}{1+(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)+xyz}\\
&=\frac{3+2(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)}{2+(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)}\\
&=1+\left(\frac{1+(x+y+z)}{2+(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)}\right)\\
&=2−\left(\frac{1+(xy+yz+zx)}{2+(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)}\right).
\end{align}

The term in brackets on the last two lines are non-negative. Thus,
$$2≥f(x,y,z)≥1$$

Comment: Hmm... yes, we can say that $2>f(x,y,z)>1$, but  that contradicts the earlier equality condition in the Cauchy-Schwarz ($a=b=c$) so it gives a loose bound.